# Spacebar Bugged? automatically closes applications

Tags: windows-8.1, keyboard, virus-removal

pressing the space bar causes programs to close. I don't know if it's a virus or what, already ran AVG anti-virus scan and it didn't help. It looks like when i click the spacebar this opens up [image]

and that's how it closes applications. If i press the spacebar multiple times it'll cycle through my open apps trying to close them... Stickykeys is off. Help please it's driving me insane.

Using Windows 8.1 and a Nighthawk x8 mechanical keyboard. I don't have other keyboards to test with but i doubt this is an issue with the keyboard

**EDIT**: Okay the issue seems to be with the keybaord, i connected it to my laptop and the same thing happens, no idea why and i can't find keyboard drivers

Answer (score 1):

Any chance your <kbd>Alt</kbd> key is stuck? Try tapping both for a moment.

The window menu you've depicted opens when using <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd>.

Comment: I connected the keyboard to my laptop and the same thing happens so it seems you are correct. Also on the log in screen pressing the spacebar multiple times makes it type `0. `. Anyway, no idea how to fix this

Comment: The weird thing is that im only having trouble with the spacebar, i wonder if the firmware could have bugged out or gotten infected or what but this is insane

Answer (score 0):

**Okay fixed it.**

Nighthawk-x8 keyboard tends to have really buggy firmware I guess (other bug with the firmware is that sometimes keys get stuck but not on a physical level), so what i did was download their keyboard-software which lets you create macros for keys in your keyboard, and just put an empty macro on the keyboard's spacebar and now it works like a normal spacebar. WEIRD. Don't purchase from MAX KEYBOARDS

Comment: Sounds really like the stored profile somehow got messed up and you changing the profile reset that.

Comment: Yep, no idea how it got messed up. I found another Nighthawk-x8 user whose firmware literally broke for no reason whatsoever [link here](https://deskthority.net/workshop-f7/help-me-flash-a-firwmare-to-revive-my-dead-keyboard-t10927.html), it's kind of ridiculous, i had to go download their macro-profile software and use it as some sort of reset.